# How to compare only one specific color of two picture using imagemagick?

Tags: compare, imagemagick

magick compare will show all the diffrence of 2 picture, but how to specify magick to compare only one color in picture.

for example, only compare blue area in 2 picture

I try check the option of magick compare command, but can't find which option can be used for
https://imagemagick.org/script/compare.php

Comment: Have you tried isolating a single color channel to compare? For example `-channel B` for blue-channel data.

Answer (score 1):

To process only a given color in ImageMagick compare, you need to create a mask for that color. Then use the read mask compare technique. See https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=31053